# export const values not binding in dropdown

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-forms

I have a constant values in separate file and bind the values in dropdown options ,  weekdays is working fine but Interval Time is bind it as object object
here is the constantvalues.ts

its working fine

```
 export const weekdays =['sunday','Monday','Tuesday','wednesday','thursday'];
```

Not working

```
   export const IntervalTime =[{key:0,value:'10.00'},{key:1,value:'11.00'}];
```

component.ts

```
 import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {weekdays} from './constantvalues';
      /**
     * @title Basic select
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'select-overview-example',
      templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
    })
    export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {
      days=[];
    
//not working[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    
    times =[];


ngOnInit(){
  [...this.days] = weekdays;
  [...this.times]=IntervalTime;
}
    }

html:
     <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="select Weekdays">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day">
          {{day}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <hr/> Second Dropdrown with Array of object
    
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="select Weekdays">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let time of times" [value]="time">
          {{time}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpmvtd?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time you should assign `time.value`, not entire object

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="select Weekdays">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let time of times" [value]="time">
      {{time.value}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Forked [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpmvtd-2rywqn?file=app/constantvalues.ts)

Comment: which is a better way i have 10 values for the timing like 10,11,12.... for that i have to create interface or model to set the type or set like this or const is better;`eg)foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];`

Comment: If those values are not changing (which should be the case for `time`), then using `constants` is a good idea. `Interface` or `model` are useful when you want to modify their properties.